# How do I get tomorrow's date in Python?

Tags: python

I am able to get today's date and time using a Python script. But I need to get tomorrow's date and time in number format. So I used the script below.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import datetime
import sys
import os

tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print "Tomorrow date is" + str(tomorrow) 
tm_stme = datetime.time(0, 0, 0)
tm_etime = datetime.time(23,59,59)
tm_stdate = datetime.datetime.combine(tomorrow, tm_stme)
tm_enddate = datetime.datetime.combine(tomorrow,tm_etime)

print "tomorrow start date:" + tm_stdate
print "tomorrow end date:" + tm_enddate  

tm_sdt_convert = time.mktime(time.strptime(tm_stdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
tm_tdt_convert = time.mktime(time.strptime(tm_enddate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

But it throws the error below:

> administrator@Ashok-Dev:~/Desktop$ python testing.py
>       Tomorrow date is2012-11-24
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "testing.py", line 13, in <module>
>           print "tomorrow start date:" + tm_stdate
>       TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.datetime' objects

I need to get `tm_sdt_convert` as a variable result. How do I get the output without error?

Comment: `tm_stdate` and `tm_enddate` are both `datetime object`

Answer (score 6):

some thing like this can help you

```
In [125]: datetime.datetime.now()
Out[125]: datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 23, 17, 11, 15, 765000)

In [126]: str(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
Out[126]: '2012-11-24 17:11:18.203000'
```

to get individual things

```
In [127]: (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).day
Out[127]: 24

In [128]: (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).year
Out[128]: 2012

In [129]: (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).month
Out[129]: 11
```

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating a string and a datetime object. Convert the datetime object to a string first:

```
print "tomorrow start date:" + str(tm_stdate)
```

If you use a comma instead, the `print` statement will do the string conversion for you and insert a space:

```
print "tomorrow start date:", str(tm_stdate)
```

or you could use string formatting:

```
print "tomorrow start date: {0!s}".format(tm_stdate)
```

If you want to influence *how* the datatime object is converted to a string, use the [`.strftime()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to format the date and time more precisely:

```
print "Tomorrow's start date: {0}".format(tm_stdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

or you could use the [`.isoformat()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) to format the string to a specific standards-compliant format:

```
print "Tomorrow's start date: {0}".format(tm_stdate.isoformat())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tm_stdate
```

is a `datetime`, not a `str`. To make a `datetime` into a `str`, you do

```
tm_stdate.isoformat()
```

or

```
tm_stdate.strftime(<some format string>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the datetime module docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

The function 'strftime' is what you are looking for. It has an example on there on how to use it. If you need additional help give me a shout.